# Elm : install specific version of a github library

Tags: elm

I want to use `v9` branch of `elm-mdl` library.

I added `native-modules` to `true` in my `elm-package.json` and added `external\elm-mdl` to my `source-directories` list.

I then added `"debois/elm-mdl": "9.0.0 <= v < 10.0.0",` to `elm-package.json`

I ran `elm-install` but it complains about :

```
  ▶ No solution found: Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `debois/elm-mdl (< 10.0.0)` required by `user-specified dependency`
- `debois/elm-mdl (>= 9.0.0)` required by `user-specified dependency`
```

How can i make `elm-install` and `elm-make` to pick up my cloned directory version of the library ?

Please see directory structure and `elm-package.json` output below :

```
└─ $ ▶ elm --version
0.18.0
└─ $ ▶ cat elm-package.json 
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "summary": "Track your life.",
    "repository": "https://github.com/user/project.git",
    "license": "BSD3",
    "native-modules": true,
    "source-directories": [
        "src",
        "external/elm-mdl"
    ],
    "exposed-modules": [],
    "dependencies": {
        "danyx23/elm-uuid": "2.1.0 <= v < 3.0.0",
        "debois/elm-mdl": "9.0.0 <= v < 10.0.0",
        "elm-lang/core": "5.1.1 <= v < 6.0.0",
        "elm-lang/html": "2.0.0 <= v < 3.0.0",
        "mgold/elm-random-pcg": "4.0.2 <= v < 6.0.0",
        "rtfeldman/elm-css": "9.1.0 <= v < 10.0.0",
        "rtfeldman/elm-css-helpers": "2.1.0 <= v < 3.0.0",
        "sporto/elm-dropdown": "1.3.0 <= v < 2.0.0"
    },
    "elm-version": "0.18.0 <= v < 0.19.0"
}

└─ $ ▶ cat external/elm-mdl/elm-package.json 
{
    "version": "9.1.0",
    "summary": "Material Design Lite port to Elm",
    "repository": "https://github.com/debois/elm-mdl.git",
    "license": "Apache License, version 2.0",
    "source-directories": [
        "src"
    ...

└─ $ ▶ ls external/elm-mdl/
build_scripts  CONTRIBUTING.md  COPYING.md  demo  elm-package.json  examples  FAQ.md  foo.md  LICENSE.md  Makefile  MIGRATION.md  PR.md  README.md  RELEASE.md  src  TEMPLATES.md  TESTING.md  tests  USERS.md
ashish @ 7567 ~/work/be_autonomous (master) 
└─ $ ▶ ls
Architecture.md  compile_css.sh  elm-package.json  elm-stuff  external    index.css  index.html  index.js  run.sh  src  TAGS  tests
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer I prepared earlier: [Using local packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28110810/using-local-packages/44469731#44469731)

In summary, remove the elm-mdl reference in your dependencies and link to the folder where the Material module is defined, ie:

```
"source-directories": [
    -- ADD src because Material.elm is under that folder
    "external/elm-mdl/src"
],
"dependencies": {
    -- REMOVE LINE BELOW
    "debois/elm-mdl": "9.0.0 <= v < 10.0.0",
},
```

It will then error for every package that elm-mdl depends on, add them locally as per the SO link I referenced above.

Comment: include all the dependencies of `elm-mdl` in your elm-package.json..
to not go into recursive dependency hell..